# Unable to call the controller function from js file using Ajax in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajax

Path of js file-

> app/code/Company/Configuration/view/adminhtml/web/js/test.js

code in js file -

```
define(['jquery', 'mage/validation', 'mage/template'], function ($, _, template) {
    function main(config, element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var path = config.AjaxUrl;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#lock").click(function(){
                var value1  = $('#value1').val();
                var value2      = $('#value2').val();
                var param = 'ajax=1';
                $.ajax({
                    /*showLoader: true,*/
                    url: path,
                    data: param,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (data) {

                    alert(data);


                });
            });
        });
    };
    return main;
});
```

And code in **phtml** file to ajax call

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {  
        "#lock": {
            "Company_Configuration/js/test":{
                "AjaxUrl":"http://127.0.0.1/magento2/admin/configuration/admin/settings/doSomeAction", "method":"get"
            }
        }
    }        
</script>
```

Where settings is controller file Settings.php and doSomeAction() is function which I want to call.

Thanks.